# Set the path of a folder

Tags: android, file, camera

I'd like to save pictures into a folder what I have created dynamically. I have a container folder which name is "Eskuvo" and inside that I can create new folders. When I open one of them I'd like to take a picture and save it inside that folder. The problem is that no matter how I give the name of the folder the app always save the picture into the "Eskuvo" folder. I copy my code:

ImagesViewF.java:

```
    public void TakingPictures(){

    File photos = new File("/sdcard/Eskuvo/"+ca.copyname+"/");
    photos.mkdirs();

    count++;
    String file = "/sdcard/Eskuvo/"+ca.copyname+count+".jpg";
    File newfile = new File(file);

    try{
        newfile.createNewFile();
    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(newfile);

    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);

    getActivity().startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 0);
}
```

I'd like to mention that `ca.copyname` is the name of the folder where I'd like to save. I hope you could help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code:

```
"/sdcard/Eskuvo/"+ca.copyname+count+".jpg";
```

will create files like these:

```
"/sdcard/Eskuvo/filename1.jpg";
"/sdcard/Eskuvo/filename2.jpg";
"/sdcard/Eskuvo/filename2.jpg";
"/sdcard/Eskuvo/filename2.jpg";
```

Use this code:

```
count++;
String file = ca.copyname+count+".jpg";
File newfile = new File(photos, file);
```

To create a file in newly created folder.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this line :

```
 String file = "/sdcard/Eskuvo/"+ca.copyname+count+".jpg";
```

You are specifying that the file should be created withing in Eskuvo directory. 
Try something like:

```
"Eskuvo/" +ca.copyname + "/" + yourfilenamehere + ".jpg"
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your String file like this:

```
String file = "/sdcard/Eskuvo/" + ca.copyname + "/" + count".jpg";
```